# Issue with pushing my changes to my repository

Tags: tortoisegit

I have just set up my computer with a clean install. My project code etc was already on a secondary D drive so is unaffected.

I installed Git and TortoiseGit.

I now try to do a **Push** and get an error about a *UriFormatException*. Then it shows the password window:

[image: Push Issue]

I can log into my repositories OK on **BitBucket** web page. So what have I done wrong?

---

The whole point is that yesterday I was able to communicate these repositories with bitbucket.

Now I can't. ChuckieAJ is correct.

But something is wrong on my setup of TortoiseGit etc.

All I know is that I can no longer push anything to my bitbucket account. It is all messed up. :(

Comment: which version of Git for Windows are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This helped me out:

https://help.cloudforge.com/hc/en-us/articles/215243143-Configure-TortoiseGIT-client-to-work-with-SSH-keys-on-Windows?mobile_site=true

I had to click on Git / Remote in each repository and correct the URL links to the new SSH locations and use the new Putty Key path.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, `ChuckieAJ` should not be part of the url -- at least not with `ChuckieAJ@` in front of it but probably with `bitbucket.org/ChuckieAJ/yourproject` or something.

Comment: I don't have a bitbucket account, so I don't know how the urls look like, but on git it's the structure I indicated above.